# Distribution certificate error:"This certificate is not yet valid."

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have downloaded distribution certificate from itunesconnect website.

By double clicking I add it to keychain access.

but in keychain access it shows me that "This certificate is yet not valid."

then what is the problem?

thanx in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is closed, but we recently had the same problem and it was due to the Mac's date / time being wrong.  Looking through the comments below, that seems to be the issue.  Hopefully this comment will help others who come here looking for help with the same issue.

Comment: Same problem. IMO, @Shog9, this question should be re-opened as it is relating to programming in a sense that it can halt you from programming if you can not proceed with testing the app on device or submission to apple with an invalid certificate. For me, marking checked **Setting -> Date & Time -> Set data & time automatically** resolved the issue. Though, I don't know why this auto time is being used in my **Keychain** while I set it manually to match my current time. Maybe a bug in apple's Mac OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 10):

Check the valid and expiration dates on the certificate and your local machine.

Comment: I have checked it everything is fine it expires in 2013

Comment: When is the starting date (maybe say "Not valid before:") and what's the date/time of the machine?

Comment: my system date and time shows me current time means Fri 17:25 IST(Indian Standard Time)

Comment: What day?  May 25?  Indian Standard Time right now is 18:07 IST (GMT + 5:30) correct?

Comment: @iglouie:Now in keychain access it shows me message "This certificate was signed by unknown authority"

Comment: @K.P. Could you mark this one closed and ask it as a new question?  Superficially it sounds like a self-signed certificate related problem.

Comment: Yes, this problem also happen to me. The reason is my local machine time is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you properly installed .cer file & Distribution profile to your MAC? Please remove it from Keychain, restart XCode & try to install .cer file & profile again