# Xcode 6.1 iOS Distribution is always revoked or missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to submit an app but I'm stuck. I can't get a the iOS Distribution signing identity to show up as valid under my account in Xcode 6.

It always shows up as revoked, never valid. I've made sure to connect it to my provisioning account on the dev site.

I also went to the developer site, revoked it there, recreated it, then went back to xcode to try to submit my app but I get this message:

[image]

When I check my account in preferences after getting this message, the iOS distribution doesn't even show up:

[image]

And when I try to add one it says:

[image]

I've tried:

- Deleting the iOS Distribution cert and regenerating it on xcode (generates as revoked)
- Deleting it and creating it on developer.apple.com
- Linked my provisioning profile to the correct app id
- Using Xcode 5 to submit my build instead

I don't know what to import or where to find a developer profile from. I've checked the dev documentation and it says the `Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate` error happens when switching mac computers, but this is all on the same machine. I am using a VMWare to run this on an virtual image of iOS Mavericks, could that be culprit?

Comment: When you create a certificate, make sure to add it to your Keychain.

Comment: I deleted my previous distributions ones and made a new one in Xcode, and it automatically generated it in my Keychain. However, when I view it in my Keychain it says `This certificate is not yet valid`. How do I validate it?

Comment: Check to make sure your computer's date is in sync with the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the time settings on your Mac are correct.

When you use a virtual machine and pause it, it pauses the time on the Mac as well. Your time settings are probably pushed back because of it, making your certificates invalid valid until a time later in the future.

For more info, see: [Distribution certificate error:"This certificate is not yet valid."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754486/distribution-certificate-errorthis-certificate-is-not-yet-valid)

Comment: Wow, that was it. My date was a few days behind.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud I just wasted a whole day on this. Thank you, this was my exact problem